# Compare all pairs from numpy.ndarrays and delete by some rule in python/numpy

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I got a tuple that contains three numpy arrays of some length that describes pairs of points.

```
dat = (is, js, dists)
```

`is` ans `js` are indices for some points and `dists` is the distance between each pair of points. There is a redundancy in `dat`, so I want to compare all pairs of pairs and check whether

```
is[n] == js[m] and js[n] == is[m] and dists[n] == dists[m]
```

is true. If the statement holds true, one of the two pairs should be deleted. Alternatively I want some new `dat2` tuple without the 'redundant' pairs.
What's the most efficient way to do this? Can I delete objects from `dat` while iterating through it?

Answer (score 0):

Create a pandas dataframe and drop duplicates.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dat)
df.drop_duplicates(inplace=True)
```

Comment: There are no exact duplicates, but I consider those redundant where a pair is the same when i and j are interchanged.